# How can i make a radio button appear checked after selecting an option (CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I hover over the text of an option and select it, the radio button should get checked. So that when I select the label, the checkbox will appear selected.

Should I add a label or make that `td` as a button?

```css
.zui-table {
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}
.zui-table thead th {
    background-color: #DDEFEF;
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    color: #336B6B;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
.zui-table tbody td {
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    color: #333;
    padding: 10px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
.zui-table-rounded {
    border: none;
}
.zui-table-rounded thead th {
    background-color: #CFAD70;
    border: none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
    color: #333;
    float: center;
}
.zui-table-rounded thead th:first-child {
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.zui-table-rounded thead th:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
}
.zui-table-rounded tbody td {
    border: none;
    border-top: solid 1px #957030;
    background-color: #EED592;
}
.zui-table-rounded tbody tr:last-child td:first-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
 
}
.zui-table-rounded tbody tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="zui-table zui-table-rounded" align="center">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4">1.Look at this series: 7, 10, 8, 11, 9, 12, ... What number should come next?</th>
            
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="question1" value="lr0101">7</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="question1" value="lr0102">10</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="question1" value="lr0103">12</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="question1" value="lr0104">13</td>
            <!--Option b-->
        </tr>
       
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a label - I assume you did not actually want to select on hover of the text ?

Like this

```
<td><label><input type="radio" 
name="question1" value="lr0101">7</label>/td>
```

Or like this

```
<td><input type="radio" id="answer1" 
name="question1" value="lr0101"><label 
for="answer1">7</label>/td>`
```